# Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia Gamma adjustment not sticking

Tags: nvidia

I have an issue with Ubuntu 18.04 Nvidia gamma setting; the adjustment does not stick. When the OS restarts, it goes back to default. I'm new to Linux and I am just stuck. I don't really know what else I need to do. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [man pages for nvidia-settings](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/alt-nvidia-current-settings.1.html) forgetting custom setting is a feature assuming that more than one person uses the computer. Section 3 of the user guide gives details about loading settings automatically using nvidia-settings --load-config-only when initializing the X server. Run nvidia-settings by itself to get the GUI version, set up the brightness, contrast and brightness as you like then save the configuration. It will be in your home directory as `.nvidia-settings-rc`. You can then modify or create the `.xinitrc` file to run nvidia-settings --load-config-only to load your custom settings automatically according to the man pages.

Comment: I tried that already and did not work. I just switched to Mint 19.3, and no more issue. Thank you anyway